# SAT with two clauses is polynomial

Tags: polynomial-math, np-complete, clause, propagation, sat

What is the complexity of a SAT instance with k unary clauses and only two clauses ?

I would like to find a paper with this result .. I found one paper in which the problem is a little bit different. All variables appears at most twice ...

Comment: Feel free to remark if answers are not okay with your question.
Or otherwise, mark the question as resolved by selecting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly this seems linear time in the total length of the clauses.

The unary clauses immediately force a partial variable assignment τ. If either of the two clauses is not satisfiable (empty) under τ, or some unit clauses are conflicting, the instance is unsatisfiable. Otherwise the instance is only unsatisfiable if the two clauses are unit and complementary under τ, i.e. x̅ and x.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has a `complexity in O(n)` where `n is the total size of clauses`.

You have K unary clauses, theses K unary clauses can be considered as an sub-assignment of variables. If you don't respect theses unary clauses, for sure you will not find the solution (if it exists).

Let's take an example to see your problem, the goal is to find values for `variables`.

```
 variables = _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
 problem   = 
              x1                 AND
              x4                 AND
              x7                 AND
             -x8                 AND
             -x5                 AND
              x2                 AND
              x3 OR  -x4 OR x5   AND
              x6 OR  -x1 OR x8

 with K = 5.
```

Because the unary clauses will propagate their values into `variables`, this problem is basically the same as :

```
 variables = x1 x2 _ x4 -x5 _ x7 -x8
 problem   = 
              x3 OR  -x4 OR  x5  AND
              x6 OR  -x1 OR  x8
 with K = 0.
```

(To obtain this, we did a linear-time operation).

And because, we already know the values of x4, x5, x1 and x8, this problem is the same as :

```
 variables = x1 x2 _ x4 -x5 _ x7 -x8
 problem   = 
              x3 AND
              x6
 with K = 0.
```

(To obtain this, we did again a linear-time operation).

And by calling the same kind of function as in the first operation, we will obtain :

```
 variables = x1 x2 x3 x4 -x5 x6 x7 -x8
 problem   = 
              true.
 with K = 0.
```

(We again did a linear-time operation to obtain this conclusion).

Which give you the final solution : `variables = x1 x2 x3 x4 -x5 x6 x7 -x8`
As you can see, to find the solution is done only by using linear time operations.